# Derivative of improper Integral $f(t)= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(xt)}{x}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm looking for the derivative of the following function
$$f(t)= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(xt)}{x}~dx$$

I tried to use $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x} =\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}dy$ and then by using Fubini changed the order of the integrals but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. The integrand may be extended as a differentiable function, one may then use the [Leibniz integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) giving
$$
f'(t)= \int_0^1 x \cdot \frac{\cos(xt)}{x}~dx=\int_0^1 \cos(xt)~dx=\frac{\sin t}{t},\qquad t>0.
$$

Comment: If you want to show it as a Hint, consider making the TeX section hidden, spoiler-like.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff To me the hint is about *proving* the Leibniz integral formula applies here...

Comment: Then please excuse me. I didn't mean to bother.

Comment: No problem, please thanks for your feedback.